# Access/SQL Server 2008 Join using Like not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, join

I apologize ahead of time because this question is in various forms many times on this site, but none of the solutions I have tried implementing seem to work properly, and I cannot find an answered question that gets me the right answer.

I am working in access for a co-worker, though it will probably be in SQL in the future once he can get a server set up. I am trying to join two tables using Like, which is easy enough, except that it just is not working properly. First, an example from each table:

T1

```
+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|LOCATION_CG_LOC_LEGACY_ID|LOCATION_CODE_DESC                                            |PI_LOW_SIDE_MW|
+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|55555-Opt01              |Autobot Transformer, 800/900 NETWORK, Optimus #1 - 800 NETWORK|5             |
+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|55555-Opt02              |Autobot Transformer, 800/900 NETWORK, Optimus #2 - 800 NETWORK|6             |
+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|55555-Opt03              |Autobot Transformer, 800/900 NETWORK, Optimus #3 - 800 NETWORK|6.5           |
+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

T2

```
+------+-----------------------------------------+------------+
|DIVID |DMT Bank Name                            |5 Digit Code|
+------+-----------------------------------------+------------+
|647531|800/900 NETWORK, Optimus #1 - 800 NETWORK|55555       |
+------+-----------------------------------------+------------+
|647532|800/900 NETWORK, Optimus #2 - 800 NETWORK|55555       |
+------+-----------------------------------------+------------+
|647533|800/900 NETWORK, Optimus #3 - 800 NETWORK|55555       |
+------+-----------------------------------------+------------+
```

I am trying to combine like items essentially, so that I can perform whatever queries I want. For now however, I am fine with a select all. I just need to combine like items. In T1, the first column [LOCATION_CG_LOC_LEGACY_ID] is a non-repeating unique item. In T2, [DIVID] is a non-repeating unique item. I was trying to query them together using

```
SELECT *
FROM [Data Table 1] INNER JOIN [Data Table 2] ON (([t1].[LOCATION_CODE_DESC] Like [t2].[DMT Bank Name]
OR [t2].[DMT Bank Name] Like [t1].[LOCATION_CODE_DESC]) AND ([T1].[LOCATION_CG_LOC_LEGACY_ID] Like [t2].[5 Digit Code] or [t2].[5 Digit Code] Like [T1].[LOCATION_CG_LOC_LEGACY_ID]));
```

Now, I think there is a problem with the second half of that join condition, but even using only the first half, I get ZERO results. However, if I edit the middle column in each table, then use the first half of that condition, it works perfectly. In other words, if I make the columns match exactly, the query seems to work, which defies the whole point in using a "like" join to begin with.

I have not yet tried this in SQL Server, but I need to get it working in Access anyway as a proof of concept at least. Any help you wonderful ladies and gentlemen can give me would be appreciated, even if it is pointing me to another thread that I have missed like a dolt.

Lastly, I am trying to avoid using VBA if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add wildcards such as `%` when using `LIKE` in sqlserver, otherwise it essentially becomes a check for equality (`=`). here is your query with wildcards:

```
SELECT *
FROM  t1 
INNER JOIN  t2 
ON [t1].[LOCATION_CODE_DESC]   Like '%' + [t2].[DMT Bank Name]+ '%' 
AND [T1].[LOCATION_CG_LOC_LEGACY_ID] Like '%' + CONVERT(varchar(50),[t2].[5 Digit Code] )+ '%';
```

Here is a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dc2b9/10/0

You'll also need to convert to `int` to a `varchar` of some sort for compatibility.

Note though, that doing a `join` on a like, especially with a convert will result in very poor performance for large data sets.

**Edit: MS Access**

MS Access will be different when you convert int to string, and uses different wildcards. I don't have access installed so can't test, but I think your MS Access query would look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM  t1 
INNER JOIN  t2 
ON [t1].[LOCATION_CODE_DESC]   Like '*' & [t2].[DMT Bank Name] & '*' 
AND [T1].[LOCATION_CG_LOC_LEGACY_ID] Like '*' & CStr( [t2].[5 Digit Code] ) & '*';
```

Comment: This seems very close to what I am trying to accomplish, but it doesn't seem to work in access.

'SELECT *
FROM  [Data Table 1] 
INNER JOIN  [Data Table 2] 
ON [Data Table 1].[LOCATION_CODE_DESC]   Like '*' & [Data Table 2].[DMT Bank Name] & '*' 
AND [Data Table 1].[LOCATION_CG_LOC_LEGACY_ID] Like '*' & CVar([Data Table 2].[5 Digit Code]) & '*''

That is the same thing converted to access. I will try it in SQL as I have found access is almost always the problem.

Comment: The Access query looks like what I thought it should be, and what I have found elsewhere, and still doesn't work. The SQL query however, works perfectly, and I thank you for it. I am going to chalk this up to Access being less robust and advise my co-worker to use SQL Server instead, as it is almost always the better options anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and look closely in like format

```
--MS SQL
SELECT  *
FROM    T1
        Inner Join T2 on T1.[LOCATION_CG_LOC_LEGACY_ID] Like T2.[5 Digit Code] + '%'

--MS ACCESS 
SELECT  *
FROM    T1
        Inner Join T2 on T1.[LOCATION_CG_LOC_LEGACY_ID] Like T2.[5 Digit Code] & '%'
```

Comment: My Mistake. I left off the & '*' from my query in access because it seemed to make no difference, but I was using "" instead of ''. However, I just tried this, and while I get a result, I get 9 rows instead of 3. Also, how do I do the join based on both conditions instead of 1 (I.E. BOTH t1.c2 like t2.c2 AND t1.c3 Like t2.c1)

Comment: You means 2 conditions must met