# MS Access join on like returning null column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables in MS Access that have the same Name_ID column, the only problem is that they differ slightly. Name_ID in table 1 looks like this:

```
Name_ID
Newton, Kate Little
River, Jane Armen
Barker, Bob Jep
Jake, Lee
```

And in table 2 it looks like this:

```
Name_ID
NEWTON, KATE L MD
RIVER, JANE A DO MS
BARKER, BOB J. (MD)
JAKE, LEE I.
```

I'm struggling with how to join the tables. I tried doing a join using like, based on [Access/SQL Server 2008 Join using Like not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21152835/access-sql-server-2008-join-using-like-not-working), but it's not working:

```
Select table1.*, table2.col from table1 
left join 
table2 
on table1.Name_ID like '*' & table2.Name_ID & '*';
```

I also tried:

```
Select table1.*, table2.col from table1
left join 
table2
on instr(table1.Name_ID, table2.Name_ID) > 0;
```

Both queries execute, but return blank columns. Any idea why it's not working, or a better way?

Comment: This is quite hard to do in SQL -- fuzzy name matching.  I would suggest that you load the data into a spreadsheet and normalize the names so they are the same.

Comment: This may be a process question and not a programming one. For reasons like this, you should not be using string literals for unique IDs but unique integers.

Comment: I agree; the names are ultimately going to be hashed, however, I need them to obtain the unique integer ID.

Answer (score 1):

Both queries are looking for a full name string within another full name string. How would you expect `Newton, Kate Little` to match to `*NEWTON, KATE L MD*`? And for the second query, `NEWTON, KATE L MD` is not within `Newton, Kate Little`.

Probably best can do is extract last name part and match on that. Assumes names are not repeated and not multiple people with same last name and always last name followed by a comma.

```
SELECT Table1.Name_ID, Table2.Name_ID
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 
ON Table1.Name_ID LIKE Left(Table2.Name_ID, InStr(Table2.Name_ID,",")) & "*";
```

Comment: I did qualify my answer with caveat can't be multiple people with same last name. Including first name might help but not if Kate is Katherine or Bob is Robert. If desire is to include first name, extraction code gets more complicated.

Comment: Indeed. From OP's sample first names appear to match. Maybe a nested `Instr`: `Left(Table2.Name_ID, Instr(InStr(Table2.Name_ID," "), Table2.Name_ID," ")) & "*"`?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, this is a case where there are multiple people with the same first and last name, so I'm going to have to separate the string and join by first and last name.

Comment: Multiple people with same first and last name? Then how will joining on first and last resolve issue? You need more identifier info - address, DOB, SSN, EMAIL.